# How much freedom should my players have regarding naming characters?

Tags: game-design

I'm currently developing a text based adventure game (original, eh?). I'm not sure how much freedom they should have in character naming.

I've thought of three options:

*Option 1:*
Predetermined names for all characters. The player is told of people's names.

*Option 2:*
Predetermined names for most characters. They are introduced in certain situations. The player picks their own name, and their best friend's name, etc.

*Option 3:*
The player picks everyone's name that they meet. If the person is killed before they are introduced (e.g. if someone is held at gunpoint and you pull the trigger), then their name is not needed to be known.

If you have any better ideas, say them. The easiest would be the first, but the second will make the player feel more involved but I think the third is too much and would become tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the use of the names. If they have a sense of humor or something eye catching about it then I'd go with option 2 as it would feel a bit rewarding to be rewarded a newer "cooler" or "funnier" name. If the names are bland and hold no significance I'd go with option 1.

Option 3 is very interesting though. But depending on the list of names the player would spend a lot time into naming NPC's instead of the actual game (unless that is your goal then go with this option).

Option 2 would give more variaty to names though with different characters having different names as at some point the player would like to use the "unlocked" name. While with option 1 the player would eventually get bored of the list and just pick them at random or name all the same.